# How to search for files and folders?

Tags: dropbox

I'm looking for the Dropbox folder on my Phone and I can't find it with my file manager. If I only had access to the `find` command it would be easier.

Comment: what file manager are you currently using?

Comment: which phone? does it have external SD- my DropBox app is downloading stuff to /external_sd/dropbox - I cannot remember if I set that as a option anywhere?

Comment: For what it's worth, mine is located at /sdcard/dropbox

Comment: @Daniel `OI File Manager`

Comment: @Al I couldn't find only because Dropbox don't create the folder on login. It creates after you download a file.

Comment: Having the same issue. Tried astro and the stock file manager. Folder used to be there or at least some apps let me download to dropbox. I can open dropbox and view files there so not sure what the deal is.

Comment: Seems to have moved recently from 'sdcard/dropbox' to '/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch'. Much easier to find...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be noted that the Dropbox app doesn't actually sync the files to your phone, it just presents you with a list. Whenever you select a file in the Dropbox app, then it downloads it to your phone. On my Incredible, the dropbox folder is just in the root of the SD card.

Answer (score 5):

[Astro File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=search_result) also has a good search function, and has a lot of handy functions connected to file management.

Answer (score 4):

[Root Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer) has an excellent search function.

Answer (score 2):

On Ice Cream Sandwich the folder is at

/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch

Answer (score -1):

I have an idea. Go to your box on your droid. Hit the menu tab. Then you will see "upload here" which is the way to upload a file from the sd card to the dropbox! Which works great for me not having internet to send from my laptop to droid as well as attaching files to inbox messages.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to explain how it will help the OP? It seems like he wanted to find the location where files are saved to his device.