# Dropbox for Android folder location

Tags: dropbox

Where does Dropbox for Android saves files when you click on "Download"?

I've read
[How to search for files and folders?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6324/how-to-search-for-files-and-folders)

But my /sdcard/dropbox is empty even if I've downloaded a file just now.

Comment: Tangentially, I'd like to recommend Dropsync for folder syncing: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync (it's free)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Dropbox 3.0 (3.0.3.2) and Sony Xperia T3:

```
/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files
```

As of Dropbox 2.0 the right location by default is

```
/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch/[files]
```

Found the things with Astro file manager (Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9).

### Moto G4 [Aaron]

> On a new Moto G4 the Dropbox app has no "star" mechanism, instead you enable the "allow offline access" option, and the actual location this file showed up was
>
> ```
> /Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/[userhash]/scratch/[‌​file]
> ```

Comment: Not really wrong, actually -- before Dropbox 2.0 this was indeed the place to find favourite/offline files, and they changed it to the obscure directory you have posted for some reason that eludes me.

Comment: i use 2.0.1 this answer is correct. the location is not in "/mnt/sdcard/download" anymore

Comment: It would likely be a change in the Android API rules that has dictated this new location.

Comment: I hate this location. It should let us choose where, and be by default set to `/mtn/sdcard/download` or `mnt/sdcard/dropbox`.

Comment: Remember that for newer Dropbox apps (mone is 2.4.7.14) you have to favorite the files first for them to be downloaded and available.

Comment: In Dropbox 3.0.3.2: /Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files (Sony Xperia T3)

Comment: On a new Moto G4 the Dropbox app has no "star" mechanism, instead you enable the "allow offline access" option, and the actual location this file showed up was `/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/[userhash]/scratch/[file]`

Comment: This is no longer the case. That folder becomes empty as of today.

Answer (score 6):

For now in the Dropbox App there is no download option, but there is favorite option (star).

When you favorite something, it downloads this for offline use in 
*sdcard/android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch*

You can do it only for files, not whole folders.

Comment: actually, there is an app for that (doing it for folders): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jjinx.dropboxdownloader or even sync'ing (paid one): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync.pro

Answer (score 5):

Dropbox on my Samsung Note 3 has its storage at `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/`.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

The default location where Dropbox will place downloaded files is `/mnt/sdcard/download` on my OG Droid.  I can't imagine it changes much between phone models.

Comment: Does not seem to be anymore, since at least does not do it very fast. Waiting now 5 minutes that the files would come to the folder in my Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9.

Answer (score 2):

As of Dropbox for Andrioid 218.2.2 (and probably earlier) offline files/folders are no longer saved in in a directory that is directly accessible to the user or to other apps. The only way to access them is through the Dropbox app.

I'm running Android 10 on a Pixel 1. `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/` used to work but it doesn't work anymore.

---

Previously I was using this to download audiobooks (stored in Dropbox) to my phone. Now that Dropbox no longer supports this, Dropsync seems to work; I recommend trying it if you have a similar use case.

Comment: Thanks, good to know - I was close to think that dropbox is a nice software.

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2019, Dropbox for Android 156.2.2 the following applies on my Huawei Nova 3i phone.

*** This applies to files where "Make available offline" has been selected *** If the file hasn't been made available offline I don't believe there is a persistent copy of it on the device, and the file contents are probably streamed when the file is accessed.

If the file is located at

```
<Dropbox>\Some folder\Somefile.txt
```

then when `Make available offline` is checked, a persistent copy of the file is placed at:

```
Main storage/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u123456/scratch/Some folder/Somefile.txt
```

For other devices `Main storage` will be different. `u123456` (obfuscated) probably identifies the Dropbox account.

A quick test seems to indicate that there is no connection in the opposite direction -i.e. I created a folder and file using an android file manager at:

```
Main storage/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u123456/scratch/test/temp.txt
```

but the file/folder doesn't appear in the dropbox image.

Answer (score 0):

The Astro file manager can connect to your Dropbox easily so that you can access your Dropbox similar to a usual folder.

You can also use it to download a whole folder (or more precisely copy a folder in your Dropbox into your SD card). Downloading is pretty slow though.

Answer (score 0):

`/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/` in LG G3 beat running Android 4.4.2.

Comment: [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/68655/96277) actually said  almost the same thing. Your answer fits as a comment to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the file to the "Downloads" folder in the normal way then click the "..." under the file and select "Save" option.

[image]