# If I open a PDF from dropbox with Adobe Reader, where is it saved?

Tags: dropbox, adobe-reader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dropbox for Android folder location](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/dropbox-for-android-folder-location)

I opened a PDF from the DropBox app with Adobe Reader on my Samsung Galaxy Tab (running 3.1). It isn't saved in Downloads, as I expected. So where is it!? I can open Adobe Reader and find it there, but I'd like to know where it has been saved on the device. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a folder on the sdcard where dropbox saves the files locally.

`/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/`