# How do I sync with DropBox?

Tags: dropbox

I want to sync DropBox with Android, so I can use the files on Android. So I installed DropBox on Android, but it won't download any files! (or at least I don't see them under `sdcard/Android/com.dropbox.android`. So I can't use the the files on Android. Did I get it wrong somehow?

I tried `Folder downloader`, but I lose the sync feature of DropBox this way. The files modified on my Android won't be synced with my laptop.

I was expecting to see `Dropbox folder` option on Android, same as on the laptop. But there's no such option.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/dropbox-for-android-folder-location

Comment: There's also this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/complete-dropbox-implementation-for-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DropSpace](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.pe.meinside.DropSpace) has some limitations according to it's description on the Play store:

```
*** current limitation:
Only files existing on the sdcard are synced.
That is, it's not a full 2-way sync.
```

I've been using [DropSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync). It does sync in both directions and I've had no cause for complaint.

Comment: I can only add that DropSync allows a single folder sync for free, and any number for a small fee.

Answer (score 4):

Oh -- I found it [DropSpace](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.pe.meinside.DropSpace) allows one to select a folder on Android -- and keep it fully synced with any (but not the root) Dropbox folder.

Comment: If this is your answer, please mark it as Answer. :)

Comment: @geff_chang He can't (yet). OP answering his own Q can mark it earliest 2 days later. But then he should, I agree :)

Answer (score 4):

To download, you need to open the DropBox app, and select the file you want to download.

To upload, you need to open the DropBox app, and select `Upload here` from the DropBox menu.

The files you see on the DropBox app are not the actual files. They are only links that are in the DropBox server, which you must download. The DropBox app for Android does not work the same way as the DropBox app for the PC. The PC version automatically downloads / syncs the file on your PC.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this @geffchang - has any sync capability been added to the latest DropBox Android (official) app in Jan 2015? Has any announcement been made for the feature to be added in a future release? Details are vague at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android

Answer (score 1):

Note Dropbox has their own implementation of this, but it's not at all the same (I recommend [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync) instead). You can mark individual files as a favorite, then they sync normally:

[Downloading (favoriting) files to your phone or tablet](https://www.dropbox.com/help/82/en)
The mobile app shows you the list of your files, but it only downloads the actual files as needed, such as when you tap on a file to view it. To ensure that a file is always on your device and up to date, mark it as favorite. This will also make it available when your device is offline.

Comment: Thank you for providing the official Dropbox help page link for this topic. While the official app may have limited support for "sync" features it is good to know where and how to try these file update capabilities.

Comment: It isn't clear to me how it knows when the file is needed. I have found that when I open some files from Dropbox, when the app opening them saves the change the file is automatically uploaded, but I don't know if they require API access to do this or if it is reliable in the sense of a more automatic app (such as a logger) being able to write data to the file now and then and have it always sync.

Answer (score 1):

[FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) is also able to sync folders with DropBox and it supports [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) automation as well.

This way you can configure - for instance - Tasker so to trigger a sync whenever you connect to your home wifi.

The only drawback is that FolderSync is not getting updates since quite a while, unfortunately.